# Obey spaces with URL package (path command)

Tags: packages, urls, paths

### Background

Using the `\path` command from the URL package to mark-up directory paths. Some of the paths have spaces.

### Problem

The preamble is set to:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% ... many other packages ...
\usepackage[automark,nouppercase]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[obeyspaces,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table,hyperref]{xcolor}
```

The code for the `\path` command:

```
\path{c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22}
```

The (PDF) output is missing the space:

```
c:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.6.0_22
```

The documentation for the URL package mentions `obeyspaces`. The documentation does not say how to enforce the parameter when the package is included indirectly.

### Question

How do you force the `\path` command to retain spaces in its parameter, without having to rewrite all the statements (to include a non-breaking space, or the LaTeX equivalent thereof)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify the option `obeyspaces` as document class option. This should then be passed to the `url` package automatically.

Comment: I would maintain that thanks are the highest form of thought, and that gratitude is happiness doubled by wonder. ~Gilbert Keith Chesterton

Comment: Would that work with beamer? I guess I'll find out soon enough...

Comment: @PatrickT I guess so, or `\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}` before loading `beamer`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that's indeed what I ended up doing: apparently `hyperref` loads `url` already so `\PassOptionsToPackage` is a pretty good way to go.

Answer (score 8):

The `url` package does not allow to set options later on with a `\urlsetup` command, so you must hack the code to get what you want. Before using this hack make sure that you cannot call beforehand the `url` package with the `obeyspaces` option either by putting `\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}` or `\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}` early enough (e.g. just after `\documentclass`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\begingroup \lccode`+=32 \lowercase
 {\endgroup \def\Url@ObeySp{\Url@Edit\Url@String{ }{+}}}
 \def\Url@space{\penalty\Url@sppen\ }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\path{c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22}
\end{document}
```