# How do you put spaces in \url?

Tags: spacing, urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obey spaces with URL package (path command)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/obey-spaces-with-url-package-path-command)
>   [How to prevent \url from removing the spaces in a path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76554/how-to-prevent-url-from-removing-the-spaces-in-a-path)

The url I want to put in `\url{}` is http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~peterf/MSc%20Examples%208.pdf

The `%20` in the url above are actually spaces. How can I type this in LaTeX so that it can be copied and pasted into a browser straight from the pdf?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Comment: I believe that the URL with `%20` is the safest mode for copy-paste.

Comment: This question is also covered by http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6948/19384

Comment: It is not difficult to find the duplicates. See the `Related` column on the right.

Comment: Also related: [How to prevent \url from removing the spaces in a path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76554/how-to-prevent-url-from-removing-the-spaces-in-a-path)

Comment: URL (or URI, URN...) can't contain space character: it's an unsafe character! A space must be encoded (`%20`). See [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).