# Spaces are not formatted correctly in url paths when using sphinx package and reStructuredText

Tags: spacing, pgfplotstable, urls, paths, restructured-text

I have a problem similar to the one in:
[Obey spaces with URL package (path command)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/obey-spaces-with-url-package-path-command).
The `obeyspaces` option is not working within the pgfplots table column.

However, my problem is slightly different because I am using reStructuredText and sphinx at the top level with a LaTeX preamble.

This is the generated output, I have very little control over any of the "auto-generated" sections:

```
% auto-generated
\def\sphinxdocclass{report}
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt, openany, oneside, english]{sphinxmanual}
\usepackage{sphinx}

% user preamble
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}

% auto-generated
\begin{document}
\chapter{Path Testing}

% user generated
\path{test path with spaces.pdf}
\path{\\testing\unc\path\name}

% auto-generated
\end{document}
```

The problem seems to stem out of the sphinx package's use of the url package, but that package is loaded before I have control over it.

On top of that, even though I CAN add the obeyspaces option to the document using the sphinx `conf.py` file it breaks UNC path names

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem (i.e., shows that `obeyspaces` is not working).  Did you try `\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}` or adding `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` around the code snippet you provided.

Comment: @PeterGrill OK.  I updated it.  Sorry, I was missing the fact that this is embedded in a pgfplots table, which may be pertinent to the problem.

Comment: I can't run your code as provided since there are numerous compile issues. After hacking away at it I was able to reproduce the problem, but adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}` _before_ the document fixed the problem. So, depending on how you are processing this file you can add that option to the command line when you run `pdflatex`.  To even get your code to run I had to remove the `obeyspaces,spaces` options to the `url` package, so if the code compiles as is for you then it should work.

Comment: You should eliminate unnecessary stuff from the MWE so we have the minimum needed to be able to reproduce the problem.  For instance is `\tableofcontents` and `\printindex` really required to reproduce the problem. I understand it is auto generated, but if you can reproduce the MWE to have less code then it will help to get to the root cause.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Yes, but as with LaTeX it is sometimes hard to be sure what is causing the side-effects.  Can you post the minimal solution that you have?

Comment: Yes, side-effects is a different issue. I suggest you eliminate chunks that seem unrelated and see if the problem still remains. The two I mentioned above are clear candidates to start with. Furthermore, if you change the `\documentclass` to something like `article` (without the document class options) does the problem still remain?  I'd post something if I thought it was going to be of any use, but I don't see how it would help you as I had to _remove_ the `obeyspaces,spaces` options to the `url` package in your code to reproduce the problem (along with some other hacking).

Comment: @PeterGrill: As for the \PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}. it doesn't seem to work for me, so I am curious where you were placing it.  I only have the power to place these commands within the preamble or document.  I do not have the power to change the document types, since it reformats the whole thing and sphinx is finicky about that.  I am trying to follow a company standard which gives me few options for documentation styles.

Comment: Right now you are just trying to determine the cause of the problem. I don't have all the packages that you have so if I can't reproduce the problem it is difficult to find a fix. So, please reduce your code to a minimum needed so that anyone can reproduce the problem as per my previous comments.  FYI, I was placing it as the VERY first line in the document _before_ `\documentclass`.

Comment: OK.  I minimized it, and even figured out the offending package for you.  However, it seems I CAN add the option to the document, but it breaks UNC paths then.

Comment: Don't think that `sphinxmanual` class or `sphinx` package are normally distributed with TeXLive2014. So removing `\usepackage{sphinx}` and changing the `\documentclass` to `book` seem to work for me. If that is also the case for you then the problem is due to either the `sphinxmanual` class or `sphinx` package.  The output I get is [here](http://i.imgur.com/mXBa37d.png).

Comment: It is the sphinx package loading that seems to cause it from my experimentation.  I don't have the option to avoid sphinx, I have no control over when it is loaded, and adding the `obeyspaces` option to the document causes path names to be spaced oddly, so this is a no-win situation.

Comment: Where can I obtain those packages to test it. I still think that adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}` as the very first line _before_ `\documentclass` should work so would like to test it

Comment: You need to install python 2.7 and the sphinx package:
http://sphinx-doc.org/